# How may I arrange the following product of two polynomials accordingly?

Tags: polynom

(1). A proper arrangement is required because some of the terms are scattered.
[image]

(2). This is how the aforementioned arrangement must look.

[image]

```
    \documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{array}
    \usepackage{booktabs}
    \newcommand*{\Ph}{\hphantom{)}}%

 \begin{document}
 $\begin{array}{r@{} r@{} r@{} r@{} r r}
 x^3 &{}+2x^{2} &{}+2x &{}+1 \\
 \times (x^2 &{}-x &{}+1) &\\
 \cmidrule{1-4}
 x^{5} & +2x^{4} &{} +2x^{3} &{} +x^{2}\\
 & -1x^{4} &{} -2x^{3} &{} -2x^{2} -1x\\
 && +1x^{3} &{} +2x^{2} &{} +2x &{} +1 \\ 
 \cmidrule{1-6}
 x^{5} &{}+ x^{4} &{}+ x^{3} &{}+ x^{2} &{}+ x &{}+ 1
 \end{array}$
 \end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this, maybe?

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{array}{@{} r *{12}{ @{}>{{}}r<{{}} } @{}}
     & x^3 & + & 2x^2            & + & 2x^{\phantom{2}} & + & 1\phantom{x^2} \\
 \times \\
     & x^2 & - & x^{\phantom{2}} & + & 1\phantom{x^2} \\
 \midrule
 & x^5 & + & 2x^4 & + & 2x^3 & + &  x^2\\
 &     & - &  x^4 & - & 2x^3 & - & 2x^2 & - &  x\\
 &     &   &      & + &  x^3 & + & 2x^2 & + & 2x & + & 1\\
 \midrule
 & x^5 & + &  x^4 & + &  x^3 & + &  x^2 & + &  x & + & 1\\
 \end{array}
 \]
 \end{document}
```

Comment: Absolutely brilliant!   I was struggling to find a solution since last weekend.   Thank you so very much!   It means a lot!